# Prove $|Up|=p-1$ when $p$ is prime and $|Up·q|= (p-1)(q-1)$ when $p \neq q$ are both prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Define $U_n = \lbrace x ∈ \mathbb{Z}_ n \mid \gcd(x, n) = 1 \rbrace$

I have figured out the following formulas,

- $|U_p|=p-1$ when $p$ is prime

  and
- $|U_{pq}|= (p-1)(q-1)$ when $p\neq q$ are  primes.

But I don't understand how to prove they are true. I have checked several examples and know the hold so far, but clearly that is not a proof that proves the formulas are true. How would i go about proving them?

Answer (score 1):

> Use the fact that $a$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z_n$ $\iff$ $\gcd(a,n)=1$

Proof:$a$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z_n\implies \exists b : ab \equiv 1\mod n\implies n\mid ab-1\implies ab-ny=1\implies \gcd(a,n)=1$

Conversely $\gcd(a,n)=1\implies ax+ny=1$ for some integers $x,y\implies [a][x]\equiv1\mod n$

If $p$ is a prime then $\gcd(a,p)=1\forall a$ such that $a$ is not a multiple of $p$. In other words $\gcd(a,p)=1\forall a$  such that $[a]\neq [0]$ in $\Bbb Z_p$ .

Hence $|U_p|=p-1$

Comment: What do you mean by the use of the $\mid$ symbol in the first half of the proof.  I've never seen it in this context before.

Comment: It means *divides*

Comment: Ah thanks. in that case you might want an $\exists y :$ on the next step when you introduce it.

Comment: Okay.Happy to help